# flower suggestion for outside the window

Tags: flowers

first of all I'm not a gardening expert so I don't know the correct terms.

I've recently put a pot outside my window and I've put some roses chinensis in it, but all its flowers fell off due to winds and also some of them dried out (the seller suggested me these flowers).

Now I need a flower for there, and I need it to be acid rain resistant (the air is polluted in here so sometimes we've got acid rains :D ), wind resistant, and highly resistant to high temperatures (42 degrees for example), and also sun hungry (here it's sunny most the time :D ).
the humidity is also not too high here (for example right now it's 12%).

thanks a lot.

Comment: How big's the pot? Height and width width will do, unless its a window box, in which case, length as well.

Comment: @Bamboo it's a ceramic one, about 25 centimeters high, about 60cm long and 25cm wide.it's quite bigger than a window box(i.e. the plastic ones).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for Pelargoniums to me - these are commonly known as Geraniums, although they're not Geraniums at all, that's an entirely different plant. Check out Pelargonium hortorum - these have thousands of varieties, most of which are grown as ornamental flowers during summer round the world. Many have zonal markings on the leaves which vary in colour from orange to red to brown to black or white. In hotter, drier countries, they survive all year, but usually aren't in flower all that time. They come in upright forms, trailing (Ivy leaved pelargonium) or cascading (fairly short cascade, commonly sold as Cascade Geranium/Pelargonium). There's also one known as Regal Pelargonium, somewhat different in flower and leaf form - very attractive, but not quite as floriferous as the other types - they usually flower, then pause, then flower again. You should get 3 or 4 in your window box (because that's what you're describing), depending which varieties you choose. Drought resistant, they hate being waterlogged, but will need feeding and watering to keep them flowering well. Largely resistant to aphids and other sap feeding insects, though flowers can be spoiled by lots of rain.

One other little thing - I'd describe your planter/window box as being 'outside' the window rather than saying behind.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry about my bad English, I'm working on it :)



(again I don't have enough reputation to vote up)

Comment: Absolutely no need to apologise - your English is fine, just thought it might be helpful to you to know how we'd say that in English usage! I knew what you meant because you said it was outside...